# How to check two NSMutableArray are having same integer numbers irrespective of order

Tags: ios, algorithm

Example:
NSMutable *Array1 contains 1,2.
NSMutable *Array2 contains 2,1.

Above condition should return True when we compare these two Array.Please help me in doing this.Thank you.

Comment: Array will contain objects, and two objects having same value "country" can not be same!!! yes Asia *a=@"country" and Europe *e=@"country". here these cant be same. so take this comparison issue. if you store only integers then its fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort both array in Ascending order like this

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
[array1 sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
[array2 sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

And then Simply compare the arrays as

```
return ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like:

```
BOOL areEqual = array1.count == array2.count;
if (areEqual) {
  NSMutableArray *array3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array2];
  for (NSNumber *number in array1) {
    [array3 removeObject:number];
  }
  if (array3.count > 0) {
    areEqual = NO;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

Here I am returning BOOL, and printing as 1 (yes), 0(no). If you want to return True and False, retrun by if-else in comparyArray:withArray: method.

```
- (BOOL)compareArray:(NSArray *)first withArray:(NSArray *)second{
    first=[first sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    second=[second sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    return [first isEqualToArray:second];
}

- (void)anyMethod{
    NSArray *arr1=@[@1,@2,@3];
    NSArray *arr2=@[@3,@1,@21];        
    NSLog(@"Compare result is %d",[self compareArray:arr1 withArray:arr2]);
}
```

Comment: If arr1 is 1, 1, 2 and arr2 is 2, 1. your method would say they are similar.

Comment: ok, i thought he want to compare each elements, now i got the question more clearly...

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume duplicates are removed (via `NSArray` > `NSSet`) then the arrays could be compared as follows:

```
BOOL equal = [[NSSet setWithArray:array1] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithArray:array2]];
```

Give consideration to the size of your arrays too.